# JLabel setText won't update but getText returns correct value

Tags: model-view-controller, netbeans, jlabel, jdatechooser

I have a little program that inputs a date from a JDateChooser component and calculates the number of days from now until the date entered.  It uses a MVC pattern, was coded in Netbeans IDE, and calculates the correct number of days but does not display it in "labelDays" which is a JLabel.  When I type in labelDays.setText("29") it works and when I get the value of labelDays.getText() it retrieves the right number of days into the future, and strDays is correct, but the label does not display the updated value.  Here is the sample code:

```
    model:
    public class CountDownModel {

        public LocalDate getCurrentDate() {
        return LocalDate.now();
    }

    public long getDays(LocalDate futureDate) {
        long daysBetween = DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), futureDate);
        if(daysBetween <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return daysBetween;
    }

    view:     
    public class CountDownView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ...       
        private CountDownController controller = new CountDownController();

        public CountDownView() {
            initComponents();
            Date input = new Date();
            Instant instant = input.toInstant();
            Date output = Date.from(instant);
            future_date.setDate(output);
        }

        private void button_calculateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              

            Date futureDate;
            futureDate = future_date.getDate();
            String strDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(futureDate);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate, formatter);

            controller.setDays(localDate);
        }                                             
        ...
        public void setDays(long days) {
            String strDays = String.valueOf(days);

            System.out.print("strDays:");
            System.out.println(strDays);

            String oldValue = labelDays.getText();

            labelDays.setText(strDays);
            labelDays.paintImmediately(labelDays.getVisibleRect());
            String newValue = labelDays.getText();

            System.out.print("oldValue:");
            System.out.println(oldValue);
            System.out.print("newValue:");
            System.out.println(newValue); 
            System.out.println("================");
        }
    }

    controller:

    public class CountDownController {
        public void startApplication() {
            CountDownView view = new CountDownView();
            view.setDays(0);
            view.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void setDays(LocalDate futureDate) {
            CountDownModel model = new CountDownModel();
            CountDownView view   = new CountDownView();

            long longDays = model.getDays(futureDate);
            if(longDays <= 0) {
                longDays = 0;
            }

            view.setDays(longDays);        
        }
    }

    main:
    public class DateCountDown {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            CountDownController controller = new CountDownController();
            controller.startApplication();
        }   
    }

    Output:
    run:
    strDays:0
    oldValue:200
    newValue:0
    ================
    strDays:28
    oldValue:200
    newValue:28
    ================
```

Thanks.  What do I need to do to make it work?
PS: I wonder if my error is due to the way I setup my MVC.

Philip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a little bit strange how MVC is set up here.

First of all, I think there is no reason to recreate `CountDownView` every time you're doing `setDays`. That may be the reason why a label does not show its new text - a new instance of `CountDownView` can be simply unvisible: an old instance of `CountDownView` is visible, while a new is not. So, here controller can have an instance of `CountDownView` as an object-level field. I can say the same about `CountDownModel`.

Futhermore, a view creates its own controller, that is not efficient, because leads to crosslinks and memory leaks. I think a constructor of `CountDownView` can accept an instance of `CountDownController` as an agrument, and store it as an object-level weak reference.

Moreover, it's a common practice to start all Swing jobs in a new instance of `Runnable`, for example:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
           CountDownController controller = new CountDownController();
           controller.startApplication();
      }
});
```

You can modify your code in the following way (hope it helps):

```
model:
public class CountDownModel {

    public LocalDate getCurrentDate() {
        return LocalDate.now();
    }

    public long getDays(LocalDate futureDate) {
        long daysBetween = DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), futureDate);
        if(daysBetween <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return daysBetween;
    }
}

view:     
public class CountDownView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
...       
    private WeakReference<CountDownController> controller;

    public CountDownView(CountDownController controller) {
        this.controller = new WeakReference<>(controller);
        initComponents();
        Date input = new Date();
        Instant instant = input.toInstant();
        Date output = Date.from(instant);
        future_date.setDate(output);
    }

    private void button_calculateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              

        Date futureDate;
        futureDate = future_date.getDate();
        String strDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(futureDate);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(strDate, formatter);

        controller.get().setDays(localDate);
    }                                             
    ...
    public void setDays(long days) {
        String strDays = String.valueOf(days);

        System.out.print("strDays:");
        System.out.println(strDays);

        String oldValue = labelDays.getText();

        labelDays.setText(strDays);
        labelDays.paintImmediately(labelDays.getVisibleRect());
        String newValue = labelDays.getText();

        System.out.print("oldValue:");
        System.out.println(oldValue);
        System.out.print("newValue:");
        System.out.println(newValue); 
        System.out.println("================");
    }
}

controller:

public class CountDownController {
    private CountDownView view;
    private CountDownModel model;         

    public void startApplication() {
        view = new CountDownView(this);
        model = new CountDownModel();
        view.setDays(0);
        view.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setDays(LocalDate futureDate) {
        long longDays = model.getDays(futureDate);
        if(longDays <= 0) {
            longDays = 0;
        }

        view.setDays(longDays);        
    }
}

main:
public class DateCountDown {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                CountDownController controller = new CountDownController();
                controller.startApplication();
             }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Added paintImmediately and oldValue variable.  Still not updateing label.

Comment: @philip-stephens, does this label update its text anytime later - or it always stay with the same value?

Comment: It always displays 0 unless I explicitly set it within the function.

Comment: And after you do `setText` on your label, how much time it takes for the label to display a new value?

Comment: If I display it explicitly it updates instantly otherwise it never updates it.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestions and fiddling around a bit I got it to work.  I am going on holidays Oct 20 so I wanted to write a program to calculate how many days are left.  Today the answer is 167 days left.